# smart pointers instead of pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, smart-pointers

Sorry for my English. I have same code:

```
auto windowsStack = m_windowManger->windowsStack();

auto ListModel = new QStandardItemModel();

while(!windowsStack.empty())
{
    auto window = windowsStack.top();
    auto title = QString::fromUtf8(window->title().c_str());

    auto Items = new QStandardItem(title);
    ListModel->appendRow(Items);

    windowsStack.pop();
}

ui->listView->setModel(ListModel);
```

everything works fine, my task is to replace the pointers to the smart pointers. I've done it more than once, my decision:

```
auto windowsStack = m_windowManger->windowsStack();

auto ListModel = std::shared_ptr<QStandardItemModel>();

while(!windowsStack.empty())
{
    auto window = std::shared_ptr<Window>(windowsStack.top());
    auto title = QString::fromUtf8(window->title().c_str());

    auto Items = std::shared_ptr<QStandardItem>(new QStandardItem(title));
    ListModel->appendRow(Items.get());

    windowsStack.pop();
}

ui->listView->setModel(ListModel.get());
```

But in the end, I get the message: The program ended unexpectedly. At the prompt, type:

```
ListModel->appendRow(Items.get());
```

New version:

```
auto ListModel = std::make_shared<QStandardItemModel>();
while(!windowsStack.empty())
{
    auto window = windowsStack.top();
    windowsStack.pop();
    auto title = QString::fromUtf8(window->title().c_str());
    ListModel->appendRow(new QStandardItem(title));
}

ui->listView->setModel(ListModel.get());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here. The first is as pointed out in the comments and Edgar Rokyans answer, that you create `ListModel` as a `shared_ptr` to null, that is first fixed by allocating an item with `make_shared`

```
auto ListModel = std::make_shared<QStandardItemModel>();
```

The more sinister error is that you are creating elements within the loop, then passing non-owning pointers to `ListModel` which become invalid at the end of the loop when `Items`'s destructor runs.  `QStandardItemModel` is [defined to delete the items it has](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#dtor.QStandardItemModel) so you shouldn't be using a `shared_ptr` to allocate items before passing them in.  Instead just allocate and call `appendRow`. Additionally you are wrapping what you get from `windowsStack` in a `shared_ptr`, but `windowsStack` seems to be a copy of a stack of owning pointers, so this is a strange thing to be doing. I can't be sure, but it looks like you actually want to either use raw pointers here, or make `windowsStack` be a stack of `shared_ptr`. I can't really be sure because I don't know what `windowsStack()` is returning - it might be a stack of owning raw pointers to dynamically allocated memory that the caller is supposed to delete.

```
while(!windowsStack.empty()) {
    auto window = windowsStack.top();
    windowsStack.pop();
    auto title = QString::fromUtf8(window->title().c_str());
    ListModel->appendRow(new QStandardItem(title));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, did you have written. The error was gone, but QListView nothing is added. While it worked with bare pointers.

Comment: you'd still need that last line `ui->listView->setModel(ListModel.get());` I was just rewriting the loop, which was flawed.

Comment: I did not remove the last line, that's what happened, I added a new version to the question above. 
so nothing was added to the qlistview.

Comment: I think I may be misunderstanding your English, извините, but if I'm not: When `ListModel` goes out of scope, it will destroy what it points to. If `ui->listView` lives longer than `ListModel` it will be a dangling pointer. If you are running on linux you should run this through `valgrind`

Answer (score 3):

```
auto ListModel = std::shared_ptr<QStandardItemModel>();
```

At this line you create an empty shared pointer `ListModel`.

Try to replace with:

```
auto ListModel = std::shared_ptr<QStandardItemModel>(new QStandardItemModel());
```

---

As Ryan pointed me out, It is better to use [std::make_shared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared), which helps to reduce the amount of the code and avoid redundant memory allocations:

```
auto ListModel = std::make_shared<QStandardItemModel>();
```

**NOTE:**

I have just described a single mistake. Seems that there are other problems in your code. Check the Ryan's answer for more details.